# Keep the footer in the bottom of the website. (Not pos: fixed)

Tags: html, css

On my [work2 Website](http://mike-kaufmann.de/work2.html) i am having problems with keeping down the footer in my page to the bottom, when there is not enough content in the page. I googled already, searched on youtube csstricks etc. 
But there are always the same "solutions"; 
but not for my page. Now i am here for some help.

What i want is [this](http://www.cssreset.com/demos/layouts/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/).
I would really appreciate a good solution.

Your sincearly.
Mike

Comment: And what's wrong with the linked solution?

Comment: @jcaron It's a HORRIBLE old method that doesn't work with footers that have a variable height.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply implement the code from the link. The keys are:

- fixed footer height, and having it absolutely positioned with `bottom: 0` inside a relatively positioned element
- content bottom padding that equals the footer height in order to push it downwards if needed

---

So, for your website, you need to add the following:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}
```

Just tested it on your website by appending it to your `style.css` file.

Comment: It's a horrible method since the footer can no longer have a variable height :/

Comment: It could if the height was set in terms of ems or percentages. There's nothing preventing anyone from using either.

Comment: @seahorsepip, horrible or not, it's **the way it's done** if you want an absolutely positioned footer.

Comment: It's not, you can still use flexbox to do exactly the same thing instead of using position absolute. Somehow time has frozen in the css world lately, I can't deny that even I waited quite a while till I looked into flexbox.

Comment: The answer I posted does exactly the same and does not require a footer with a specific height.

Answer (score 0):

Move your footer inside the body, it's invalid html otherwise. Also you can use flex to simply stretch the content to fill the space left over on the screen:

```
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#content {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Why use this method? Simple, footers don't need a specific height this way, it can be variable in height if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the example that you provided, you'll see that the html and body tags both have the height attribute set to 100%, and the wrapper div has a min-height of 100% and is set to relative.

That allows the footer div in the example to be absolutely positioned on the bottom of the wrapper div, which also happens to be the bottom of the page.

If you have Chrome, open up the DOM inspector and select the html or body tag (your choice), the wrapper div, and the footer div in that order and you'll be able to follow along.

Comment: I tried it already, but it doesnt seems to work.

Comment: Can you create another page where you've tried it? Call it work3.html or something like that. Maybe there's something mistyped or that you've forgotten that we'll be able to see with fresh eyes. 

I don't see it in the work2.html page.